# Creating an SD card on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am trying to create an SD card on emulator, but am getting following error:

> Failed to create SD card

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: what u did for create sdcard?

Comment: How did u create the AVD? Using ADT plugin or using the command prompt?

Comment: windows->Android sdk and Avd manager i allocated memory for sd card there itself i found an error telling that "Failed to create SD card"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had faced the same issue on my Linux machine. My solution:

Go to the Tools folder in the Android SDK directory. Make sure you have execute permissions on all files in the location. 
I had to change permissions to 777 (Read+write+execute) for all files and the issue was resolved.

For a detailed explanation: [Wordpress link](http://wditot.in/2011/05/25/android-failed-to-create-sd-card-emulator-crashes-instantly/)

UPDATE: A lot of people are facing issues on their 64-bit Windows machines. Please try the StackOverflow threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288142/windows-7-64bit-android-avd-start-errorfailed-to-allocate-memory-8) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629109/eclipse-64-bit-android-virtual-device-manager-failed-to-create-sd-card). Hope these help

Comment: In my case it was a different issue altogether. My 64-bit Linux was missing the 32-bit glibc. Refer this helpful post on [lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=268429#post1504144)