# Eclipse 64-bit - Android Virtual Device Manager Failed to create SD card

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, windows-7-x64, android-virtual-device

I am running Windows 7 64-bit and Eclipse also 64-bit with the latest ADT plugin installed and the Android ADK. All installed as instructed on the Android SDK site.

When I try to create a new AVD I get the following messages.

[*Date* *Time* - SDK Manager] Failed to create the SD card.
[*Date* *Time* - SDK Manager] Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.

I have tried different SD card sizes thinking It may be something to do with storage space allocation but that doesn't seem to be the case as my hard-drive has a lot of space left. Considering I have admin rights on my account it shouldn't be that it can't create a folder either. I really have no idea what is going wrong here and all I have been able to find on this are post on Ubuntu, which haven't been much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the following directory in your computer:

C:\Users\.android\avd

Inside this directory you will find all files and directories with the definition and content of your avd machines-

Now do the basic troubleshooting steps:

-check if the avd directory exists and if it contains a file with the name "sdcard.img".

-if the file exists, try to rename it (to check if its locked) and then go to eclipse and ask to create a new sd card.

-if it fails, try to create manualy a file with that name to check premissions.

good luck

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The avd folder is completely empty. I created a file "sdcard.img". I can rename it no problem. Tried with eclipse again and it still wont create the SD card image. I even tried running eclipse in admin mode, not that it should matter, didn't work either.

Comment: That's strange, avd folder shouldn't be empty. You should have a file avdname.ini and a folder avdbname.avd per virtual machine. Inside the avdbname.avd folder you should have several .ini and .img files. Are you checking the write location?

Comment: It didn't work on the first virtual machine I tried to create. Unless the SDK comes with VMs there shouldn't be any in there.

Comment: So your problem in not creatinh the sdcard, but creating the avd. Correct? Do you have any spaces in the name of the directory where the SDK is installed or in windows user directory?

Comment: So, that worked. It seems that the space was the problem. Which leads me to my next question. Did I time travel back to the 90's? Since when can programs not deal with spaces anymore?

Comment: I can rename it but new AVD still cannot be created ...could you please help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419733/throwable-failed-to-create-the-sd-card)

Answer (score 1):

I found similar issue on my windows. Seems like this happen for 64 bit machines only. To solve this, make sure you have full access permission to all files under the Tools folder in Android SDK directory.
For linux/ubuntu, execute the following

```
 chmod -R 777 ../tools
```

For windows, goto Android SDK directory..

Right click Tools folder > Properties > Go to tab "Security" > Select "Users" > Edit > Select "full control", save and close it.

It should work after doing this

Answer (score -2):

Close the emulator which is in open, and re-try.  This worked for me.