# How to set android device on eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am a newbie and trying to run my first application on Android. The steps that I followed to create a new device are as following: (O/S is Mac OS X Version 10.7.5)

**Steps**

```
1- opened Android Virtual Device(AVD) Manager
2- Clicked on Device Definitions
3- Choosen Nexus 4 by Google
4- Clicked on Create AVD
5- In AVD the settings are as shown in the image.
6- I click on ok but the console shows following error messages.
```

**Output**

```
[2014-10-22 13:28:16 - SDK Manager] Failed to create the SD card.
[2014-10-22 13:28:16 - SDK Manager] Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.
```

[image: Settings]

Comment: Can you verify that you have write permissions on the AVD folder?

Comment: @PaulRatazzi where the AVD folder is?

Answer (score 0):

I've never had much luck with the standard Eclipse AVD, usually run into nuisances and errors in it. I'm not trying to advertise here or anything but a free program, [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) has worked for me. It runs like any other virtual device, once you have the device running you can run your app on it from eclipse too. Has all the options that the normal virtual devices has.

As for your issue, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629109/eclipse-64-bit-android-virtual-device-manager-failed-to-create-sd-card) stack overflow should help.

Key info of linked URL:

> Go to the following directory in your computer:
>
> C:\Users.android\avd
>
> Inside this directory you will find all files and directories with the
>   definition and content of your avd machines-
>
> Now do the basic troubleshooting steps:
>
> -check if the avd directory exists and if it contains a file with the name "sdcard.img".
>
> -if the file exists, try to rename it (to check if its locked) and then go to eclipse and ask to create a new sd card.
>
> -if it fails, try to create manualy a file with that name to check premissions.

Comments:

> So your problem in not creating the sdcard, but creating the avd.
>   Correct? Do you have any spaces in the name of the directory where the
>   SDK is installed or in windows user directory?

You could also manually create an SD card through the [mksdcard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/mksdcard.html) command

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by upgrading my O/S to OS X Yosemite.

To download and install this new O/S type its name in the app store or Google.

Answer (score 0):

Your AVD Folder Should be in this

```
C:\Users\.android\avd
```