# Throwable: Failed to create the SD card

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-service

PLEASE HELP. My AVD is not running as I have posted at [AVD not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417842/avd-not-running?noredirect=1#comment54627849_33417842). I tried to create a new AVD but get this error

> Throwable: Failed to create the SD card.

How to solve this? Really need help seriously...Thanks

Comment: Assuming you are running windows. Try this: "Go to Android SDK directory -> Right click Tools folder > Properties > Go to tab "Security" > Select "Users" > Edit > Select "full control", save and close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Whats your logcat throws

> Throwable: Failed to create the SD card.

At First you need to download the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/index.html), launch the **`Android SDK Manager`**, *install the Android SDK Platform-tools* .
Then check [Install Intel HAXM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418450/i-cant-install-intel-haxm) .I hope it will helps you .

Answer (score 10):

**EmptyThrowable: Failed to create the SD card.**

**UBUNTU:** Open your terminal and **install** this

**sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6**

Answer (score 9):

The solution in my case, Fedora 24, was to install the 32-bit version of the glibc and libgcc libraries.

```
$ sudo dnf install glibc.i686
$ sudo dnf install libgcc.i686
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: Definitely did help me! Was so confused having followed all the other "fixes"

Answer (score 1):

Go to your android studio and android sdk folders and make all directory and files executable by this command :

```
chmod +x -R *
```